# Disappearing Pictorial Elements in Flash CS6 File

Tags: flash, png, mp4, avi

I am using Flash CS6 to do an animation. You can see it here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S2tB5wP2etU

I am populating a cemetery with the locations of war veterans' graves. When the person is born, their name pops up on the list at the bottom. When he reaches age 20, his name turns red so you can see at a glance during which war he might have been active. After ten years, they go back to green, although I may change that.

When the vet dies, their name drops off the list and their headstone appears. I animated this by putting a blank JPG of the empty cemetery on the bottom layer, then insert individuals headstones as PNGs with transparent backgrounds. In order to make sure the headstones appear in the proper location, I deleted the backgrounds but kept the overall size and format so that they pop correctly into place.

You can see the problem around the 1:04 mark. One of the headstones disappears for absolutely no reason. It's formatted exactly the same as all the other elements, but no matter what I do, it disappears when the 1818 grave appears. I tried pulling the 1818 headstone further down in the layer list so that it was below the layer with the disappearing object. The problem remains. As you can see by watching the rest of the video, a bunch of other graves start jumping around.

I got my first presentiment of this problem last night when I was not able to make the final image fade smoothly back to the fully populated cemetery. Instead, it suddenly jumps to the final image with no transition. My work around on that was to do the last two seconds as a separate animation (absolutely no problem doing this) and joining them together.

Could it be a memory issue? A corrupt file? Should I try to break the file out into smaller segments? Anyone have a workaround?

Thanks,

Marc

Comment: Will it be correct if I assume that you put each grave on its own layer, so it's like you have ~2000 layers there, each one has some content from a certain frame on?

Comment: Not that many! There are two fullsize JPGs on separate layers, then 49 PNG files, 49 text layers, and the years, wars, and title layers. So altogether around a hundred layers. The PNGs and text layers are in two folders.

Comment: Well, I never worked with that many layers before, they just might be the reason of your problems. If I were up to animating something like that, I'd make it in two layers: bottom final picture and top initial picture in a form of bitmap fill (you can "break" raster object into fill through some menus, I remember). So, instead of adding more layers, each time I need a new stone to appear, I'd just make a keyframe on the top layer and cut a small (preferably rectangular) window to the bottom layer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. I may just insert the images one after each other in the same order on a single time line. That blows up the file size real fast, though.

Comment: You might also want to split it into phases. Like, every 10 or 20 stones you remove stones and change the background picture (like setting a keyframe), so there's always a reasonable and manageable amount of different objects present on stage. The total weight will not get out of hand either, because the amount of distinct images will be not that great.